# How to update an approved open graph action?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

I have an approved open graph action. I want to make a simple update to it (change "on AppName" to "via AppName").

How do I do this? That field isn't editable on the action update page. Do I have to delete the action, re-create it, and re-submit it? Is there a way to do it without disabling the action to users in the mean time?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGraph action verb are subjected to be approved by Facebook , so i guess you can 't change it once approved but only delete and create new

Comment: This does work, but if you actually delete the event then it deletes the actions already published by users. If there is no better solution, it does work to create a 2nd action but I'd recommend not deleting the first.

Comment: @Dave:Can you please provide me,things that required for approve the actions.? I Have followed their action Doc, But I got an reply that "Your usage instructions are incomplete or difficult to understand. Please write step-by-step instructions so that a user can trigger the action and resubmit.
Please make changes below and resubmit for review"